Excessive Ripple and Fluctuations in Buck Converter Output Using ME3116
I'm experiencing strange behavior with my buck converter. My input voltage is 5V, and I'm aiming for a set output voltage of 3.3V. However, the output is fluctuating significantly, as observed on the oscilloscope, even though the load is only drawing 10mA.
The buck converter IC I'm using is the ME3116, but I'm unsure what's causing these fluctuations and excessive ripples in the output. Could someone help identify the potential issue or suggest troubleshooting steps?
he same schematic with a layout designed by another designer is working fine. I have also attached that layout for reference. Can you please check if there are any issues with the current layout?








What is input voltage (waveform)? Load current? Is it getting hot?

@TimWilliams The load current at this moment is 10mA, and the IC is not getting hot, but it is providing unstable voltages on two of my boards. A buck converter with the same schematic, but with a layout designed by another designer, is working fine. I believe there is an issue with the layout. Can you review it?

I reviewed the layout. Could you please answer the question [input voltage]?  Have you inspected the assembly, perhaps there are bad solder joints?  Have you tried swapping parts between "good" and "bad" designs (to see if a bad component or incorrect value is present, or it is in fact due to layout)?

I'm guessing your C1 470 nF feedforward capacitor is a couple orders of magnitude too high. This can upset the control loop so that you do not get a steady output voltage.
The datasheet gives these reasonable limits:

In general, the feedforward capacitor range is
between 10pF to 220pF.


Thank you for pointing out the feedback capacitor; it could be an issue, so I’ve changed it. However, the same schematic with a layout designed by another designer is working fine, but this layout is behaving the same way on two of my boards. Can you check the layout to see if there is any problem with it?

So you have changed/removed the C1 capacitor and tested it again and it still looks the same as before?

Yes, it's approximately the same.
